# How can i fix flutter doctor (error code -27)

Tags: flutter

[image: Terminal Command]

Error: Browsing on the local area network for ideal insane. Ensure the device
is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area
network as this Mac.
The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code
-27)

i want to fix it. but i don't know why it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you try to connect an iOS/iPadOS device, you can try to enable developer mode on the device by following this [link](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/ios-developer-mode/#) (this is an expo tutorial but same for Flutter :) ).

Then try to open an Xcode project, then go to `Window` -> `Devices and Simulators` you should see your device status (it can show you a warning that need to connect in USB first to enable wireless feature/prepare for development).

Comment: I solved it. Thank you for your help!